# How does GroupActionBase affect the order of elements in a group?

Tags: group-theory, algebra

**Related (math.SE):** [How does the base of a group determine the “sort” of the elements in the group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752815/how-does-the-base-of-a-group-determine-the-sort-of-the-elements-in-the-group/754382?noredirect=1#754382)

The help page for `GroupActionBase` says:

> - A base of a group is a list of points of its domain of action such that the only element in the group fixing them all is the identity.
> - Reordering the points in a base gives a different base.
> - The choice of base affects the ordering of group elements in the functions `GroupElements` and `GroupElementPosition`.
> - If the list of points given is not a base, Mathematica will add more points until obtaining a base. In particular, `GroupActionBase -> {}` will make Mathematica choose an appropriate base.

It doesn't explain **how** the order of points in a base affects the order of the elements in a group. Since this is pretty much exactly what you need to know in order to use `GroupActionBase`, at a minimum should have been included in the help file. ;-)

They do include a single example (that wasn't very illuminating for me), which I'll include below for easy reference.

So bullet 1 specifies that a base needs enough points such that only the group identity will fix all the points in the base, and bullet 4 says if you don't provide a full base, Mathematica will add points (via some unspecified methodology) until it's a base, but this doesn't explain how the order of the points in the base relates to the order of the elements of the group.

From bullet 1 and the example, it's apparent that a base is a flat list of the same positive integers that the `Cycles` notation operates on.  However, the group $S_n$ (the example below is contained inside $S_4$) operates on a set of $n$ elements, and there are $n!$ ways to order them in a base.  But $S_n$ itself has $n!$ group elements, meaning there are $(n!)!$ ways to order the elements of the group.  **Can anyone clarify how specification of a base via `GroupActionBase` effects the order of the group elements reported by `GroupElements` and `GroupElementPosition`?**

**Basic Examples (1)**

```
Elements of a group in standard order:

In[1] := GroupElements[PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}], Cycles[{{1, 3}}]}]]
Out[1]:= {Cycles[{}], Cycles[{{2, 4}}], Cycles[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}],
          Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4}}], Cycles[{{1, 3}}], Cycles[{{1, 3}, {2, 4}}],
          Cycles[{{1, 4, 3, 2}}], Cycles[{{1, 4}, {2, 3}}]}

In[2] := OrderedQ[%, Less]
Out[2]:= True

Sort them, specifying different priorities with a base:

In[3] := GroupElements[PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}], Cycles[{{1, 3}}]}], 
          GroupActionBase -> {4, 2}]
Out[3]:= {Cycles[{}], Cycles[{{1, 3}}], Cycles[{{2, 4}}], 
          Cycles[{{1, 3}, {2, 4}}], Cycles[{{1, 4}, {2, 3}}], 
          Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4}}], Cycles[{{1, 4, 3, 2}}], 
          Cycles[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]}
```

Comment: This is not an official Wolfram Research site, so complaints concerning the inadequacy of _Mathematica_ documentation, however valid, are not really appropriate. Perhaps you might do better by posting this on the [Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/). As an alternative, you might edit the question to ask something specific about `GroupActionBase`. Someone may be able to answer a well-posed specific question.

Comment: Apologies if my wry attempt to inject humor into a technical topic offended.  I realize this isn't a Wolfram site, but I've noticed anecdotally that the SE communities are typically faster than corporate run support systems. (With the exception of XBox's Twitter Support, they impress me.)  Come to think of it, Wolfram support in particular I've not been happy with.  In the past, they've taken weeks or months to return my support emails.  I was not aware of that forum, and if SE doesn't satisfy, I'll consider biting the bullet and registering yet another account in another community.

Comment: How can I make the question more specific or more well-posed?  I know nothing about `GroupActionBase` or how Mathematica decides the order of group elements.  As a math PhD student I've never even heard of bases for groups before and was shocked when I looked it up to find it wasn't just a Mathematica term/convention.  I felt the question was fairly narrowly focused.  I'm not asking about groups or algebra in general, but specifically in Mathematica, how does a specified base determine the order of elements in the group it's applied to?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm not proposing you delete your question, nor am I going to vote to close it. I simply am pessimistic about your getting an answer to it in its current form. I sincerely hope that my pessimism is misplaced.

Comment: One way you might improve your question is to add a one sentence paragraph at end. "Can anyone fill in the holes I have found in the documentation article?"

Comment: I assume @TravisBemrose meant "it was just a Mathematica term" ( GroupActionBase. - ( I am trying to figure out what I can and can't do with Group Theory in Mma at the moment. )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me try to explain this. The key idea with bases is that even when you work with a group action on a set of n objects numbered 1 to n, you actually can identify the individual group elements by how they act on the elements of a base, which is frequently much shorter.

For example, take the

```
In[1]:= group = DihedralGroup[6];
```

It has 12 elements, sorted by default as given by

```
In[2]:= elems = GroupElements[group];
```

You can see the base chosen by Mathematica using

```
In[3]:= base = GroupStabilizerChain[group][[-1, 1]]
Out[3]= {1, 2}
```

This means that we do not have to control how the group acts on the 6 points, but it is enough to keep track of how the group acts on {1, 2}. Note that these pairs of images are all different, and that they are sorted in standard order:

```
In[4]:= PermutationReplace[base, elems]
Out[4]= {{1, 2}, {1, 6}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {4, 5}, {5, 4}, {5, 6}, {6, 1}, {6, 5}}
```

Imagine you want to use a different base, one that starts with {5, 2} for example. Use

```
In[5]:= GroupStabilizerChain[group, GroupActionBase -> {5, 2}][[-1, 1]]
Out[5]= {5, 2, 4}
```

Mathematica tells you that {5, 2} is not a base. That is because the images of {5, 2} do not uniquely identify the elements of the group. There are repeated pairs of images here:

```
In[6]:= PermutationReplace[{5, 2}, elems]
Out[6]= {{5, 2}, {3, 6}, {4, 1}, {6, 3}, {5, 2}, {1, 4}, {6, 3}, {2, 5}, {1, 4}, {3, 6}, {4, 1}, {2, 5}}
```

However, {5, 2, 4} is a base. Actually {5, 4} is a base (2 is redundant) so let us use {5, 4} in what follows:

```
In[7]:= newbase = {5, 4};
```

In standard {1, 2, 3, ...} order we give first priority to 1, then to 2, etc. With the base {5, 4} we worry first about what happens to 5, then to 4. Then the rest in standard order, so we have {5, 4, 1, 2, 3, 6}. A key fact is that we always want to have the identity sorted first. Because we have a base, we know that only one of our permutations maps 5 to 5 and 4 to 4, and that must be the identity. Check it:

```
In[8]:= PermutationReplace[newbase, elems]
Out[8]= {{5, 4}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {6, 5}, {5, 6}, {1, 6}, {6, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 2}, {3, 2}, {4, 3}, {2, 3}}
```

Note that we have again different pairs of images, but now they are not sorted in any obvious way. The good way to sort them with the new base is

```
In[9]:= newelems = GroupElements[group, GroupActionBase -> newbase];
```

The identity is still the first one:

```
In[10]:= newelems[[1]]
Out[10]= Cycles[{}]
```

but the rest are sorted differently:

```
In[11]:= elems === newelems
Out[11]= False
```

To explain what has happened, look at this:

```
In[12]:= newimages = PermutationReplace[newbase, newelems]
Out[12]= {{5, 4}, {5, 6}, {4, 5}, {4, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 6}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {3, 2}, {6, 5}, {6, 1}}
```

Remember the priorities {5, 4, 1, 2, 3, 6}.

You can also compare the order of elems and the order of newelems:

```
In[13]:= order = Flatten[Position[elems, #] & /@ newelems]
Out[13]= {1, 5, 3, 11, 9, 6, 8, 12, 2, 10, 4, 7}

In[14]:= PermutationReplace[newbase, elems][[order]] === newimages
Out[14]= True
```

Or you can think about it in this alternative way:

```
In[15]:= PermutationReplace[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, newelems] // Column
Out[15]= {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
         {3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4}
         {2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 3}
         {6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
         {5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6}
         {3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2}
         {4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3}
         {6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}
         {1, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2}
         {5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4}
         {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1}
         {4, 3, 2, 1, 6, 5}
```

First you try to put 5 in its place (look at the first two lists). Then you try to put 4 in its place. It will be possible in the first of those two (the identity), but not in the second one. Then you try to put 4 in the fifth place, and then you worry about what to put in the 4th place, etc.

This is all rather technical, though standard in computational group theory. Bases are not typically needed in standard operations with groups, but bases and strong generators are at the core of the internal algorithms. For example, if you want the stabilizer of a group by some point p then it helps to have p as the first element in the base. GroupStabilizer will do those changes of base internally for you. GroupActionBase can also be useful with large groups, because performance of various operations can be very different for different bases of the same group.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I follow until you use the pure function at `In[13]`.  I haven't quite figured them out yet.  I also forgot to link the related question on math.SE.  We've figured out that the first several group elements given by `GroupElements` are the ones that fix the first point in the base, and then the next several group elements are the ones that also fix the second point, etc.  It's within those elements that fix the next point, I don't see how those are sorted yet.

Comment: BTW, I appreciate the thorough answer!  I see what's happening at `In[12]`, but I don't see how your comment "Remember the priorities {5, 4, 1, 2, 3, 6}" relates to it.

Comment: For example, I ran  `elems=GroupElements[SymmetricGroup[4],GroupActionBase->{3,2,4,1}];` `PermutationReplace[{1,2,3,4},elems]//Column` and got `{1,2,3,4}, {4,2,3,1}, {1,4,3,2}, {2,4,3,1}, ...`.  I get the first two, but it seems to me the next 2 should be switched.  It had to move 2, but instead of putting it in the lowest priority place first (1), it put the 2 in the 4th place, which had higher priority.

Comment: Working with permutations there is always the feeling that you could/should reverse something. You would end up sorting the inverses, which typically gives a different result. In your example with base {3,2,4,1}, you first fill slot 3 with point 3, and then you can fill slot 2 with point 2 for the first two permutations, but not for the third. Hence in the second slot you put 4, which is the next point of the base. Then you have to fill slot number  4, and you have already used points 3 and 4, so you take 2, because it is before 1 in your base. That explains the third permutation.

Comment: Concerning my comment after Out[12], take the first elements of all pairs. You get 554411223366. Compare with the list of priorities {5, 4, 1, 2, 3, 6}. Then for each pair of second elements, say 53 for first element 4, note that 5 is before 3 in that list.